# Jupyter Notebooks Hang in Browser on Windows 10

Tags: r, windows-10, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I just installed Miniconda and the R Essentials bundle on my Windows 10 machine, following the instructions given [here](https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer/jupyter-and-conda-r). Everything went swimmingly until I opened up an Anaconda command prompt and entered `jupyter notebook` and got an error. I then used `ipython notebook` which worked, so okay, no problem there.

However, after creating a new folder and trying to create a new R notebook within that folder, my Jupyter tabs started to hang. Whenever I try to do something, whether it is rename the notebook, run a block of code, basically anything, all of the Jupyter tabs sit there loading endlessly saying "Waiting for localhost..."

I try stopping the server and restarting it, but every time I try to do anything I get the same result. I also tried changing the port and running the command prompt as administrator--same result. I am using Chrome, which shouldn't be an issue.

Any ideas? I was really excited about using a Jupyter notebook to keep track of my analyses in R, but if I can't even get it to function out of the box I'll have to find a better solution.

Comment: With "Anaconda command prompt", do you mean the Windows command prompt?

Comment: Yes, a Windows command prompt that starts in the Anaconda directory.

Comment: Is it specific to R, or does the same happen with Python notebooks? Do you have any internet security software on your machine? Some 'security' systems block the notebook's websockets. Sometimes changing the URL between `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` helps, but not always.